# how to get proper UIWebView content height?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am add UIWebView in View and That view in ScrollView.

I want to get frame of the UIWebView Content. So can I set the frame to view and scrollview?

I know we can get the height by using javascript. As mention below:

```
float height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] floatValue];
```

But when I am rotating the view and recalculate the height of the UIWebView content in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation::(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` method, then content height was increased.

So please suggest me how can I get the proper height when i am rotate the orientation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adopt this method:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    CGRect frame = wvContent.frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [wvContent sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    wvContent.frame = frame;
}
```

Then call this method everytime device rotating:

```
- (void) reloadContent
{
    CGRect frame = wvContent.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    frame.size.width = wvContent.frame.size.width; // you should change webview's width here.
    wvContent.frame = frame;

    [wvContent loadHTMLString:yourHTML baseURL:nil]; // reload webview
}
```

Hope that help :)

Comment: And here is my code to take a look: http://files.myopera.com/minesh1/Demo_Source/tableViewTest.zip

Comment: in this web view have extra white space in bottom after device rotating.

Comment: Add this code in viewdidload 
wvContent.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

Comment: ok let me take a look at your code first. I will send you soon :0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are retrieving height when all the content is loaded.

You can add a method to calculate height in `UIWebView`'s delegates method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    float height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] floatValue];
}
```