# UIWebview document height after rotation in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, height, document

I have an UIWebView and i get the document height on the webViewDidFinishLoad event like this:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {

    heightWebView = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"webview height: %f", heightWebView);

}
```

On the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` event i am reloading the webView html string. I don't know why is getting the same document height in landscape and in portrait mode.

Any solutions?

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087002/how-to-get-proper-uiwebview-content-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the frame for both portrait and landscape orientation.

with the help of **CGRectMake** method

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [_ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 470)];
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait){
        [_btnBooks setFrame:CGRectMake(116, 29, 86, 88)];
    }
    else
    {
        if (IPHONE5) {
            [_btnBooks setFrame:CGRectMake(240, 29, 86, 88)];
        }
        else
        {

            [_btnBooks setFrame:CGRectMake(196, 29, 86, 88)];
        }
    }
}
```